# differences between (m = cin.get())!=EOF&m = cin.get()!=EOF

Tags: c++

I don't know why these two codes are acting differently.

I wrote some code which receives user input then prints it out.

I think the first one, `(m = cin.get())!=EOF`, acts like one character saved at `m`, then `=` returns 1 (because 'save' is success) and `while` loop never ends (because of `1 != EOF`).

And the second one, `m = cin.get()!=EOF`, acts like I want. Because the character typed is saved in `m` then `m != EOF` is what i mean.

1.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char m=0;
    while((m = cin.get())!=EOF){
        cout << m;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

2.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char m=0;
    while(m = cin.get()!=EOF){
        cout << m;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: precedence of the operators perhaps?

Comment: Why do you believe "successful save" returns 1? There is no success code to indicate something was "saved"; the result of assignment is the value assigned (so `(m = cin.get())` assigns to `m` and evaluates to the same result as `m`). That said, `cin.get()` returns `int`, not `char`, and `m` should be declared as such; `EOF` is outside the range `char` can represent, so if `m` isn't declared as `int`, the loop will never end. If you do `m = cin.get() != EOF`, the loop will eventually end, but `m` will only ever have one value in the loop, `1` (the result of comparing `cin.get() != EOF`).

Comment: @EdHeal Thank you so much i know what you saying. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh your great! I know all of yours. So I test with this code
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

 int m, n;
 n = (m = 3);
 cout << n << endl;
 return 0;
}
then, I really understand my mistake. Thank you so much! You will be blessed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct, and Ed Heal in the question's comment is also correct: This is an example of the importance of [operator precedence.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

In the `(m = cin.get())!=EOF` case, this is basically what's happening:

```
m = cin.get();
while (m != EOF) { ... }
```

In the `m = cin.get()!=EOF` case:

```
m = (cin.get() != EOF);
while (m) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my english.  And I really understand what you mean. Thank you so much. I think all of stackoverflow users are angel. ~_~ b

Comment: Our pleasure :)